# I need to subtract the count and update the remaining count

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using TextField that field data I am adding into the table that works fine what my task is I have one field called **Total no of count** their I am storing my data count so whenever I add data into the table it will be based on the count, mean like example if I have count 3 then I am able to use count max 3 or if I want to divide that count with a different name that also works only max count I used whatever present in **Total no of count** or after dividing count with a user name I need to update remaining count in that field  or whatever count is present after added into a table showing remaining count when I use all count in one time or add it to the table that works fine mean **Total no of count** get subtracted with table data count and remain 0 but when I divide that count into 2 or 3 names field mean by 1 by 1 then it will not work properly mean count not get subtracted properly

In this method, I am subtracting and setting the remaining count

```
  const totalRemainingCount =
    totalUsers -
    Number(
      AssignSearchesForm.values.countAssigned ||
        teamdata?.map((data) => data.countAssigned)
    );
```

```
export default function App() {
  const [teamdata, setTeamData] = React.useState([]);

  const AssignSearchesForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      selectName: "",
      selectAge: "",
      location: "",
      countAssigned: ""
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, formikHelper) => {
      setTeamData([values, ...teamdata]);
      formikHelper.resetForm();
    }
  });

  let filteredArray = nameList.filter(
    (e) => !teamdata.some((data) => data.selectName === e.selectName)
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedName = e.target.value;
    const name = nameList.find((data) => data.selectName === selectedName);
    const newOptions = Object.values(name).reduce((optionList, key) => {
      optionList.push({ value: key, label: key });
      return optionList;
    }, []);
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("selectName", selectedName);
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("selectAge", newOptions[1]?.value || "");
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("location", newOptions[2]?.value || "");
  };

  const totalUsers = 3;
  const totalRemainingCount =
    totalUsers -
    Number(
      AssignSearchesForm.values.countAssigned ||
        teamdata?.map((data) => data.countAssigned)
    );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card color="primary" variant="outlined">
        <CardHeader
          title={
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              Total no of count ={" "}
              {totalRemainingCount <= 0 ? 0 : totalRemainingCount}
            </Typography>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                sx={{ minWidth: 185 }}
                select
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="Select Name"
                name="selectName"
                size="small"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={AssignSearchesForm.values.selectName}
                error={
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.selectName &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.selectName
                }
                helperText={
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.selectName &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.selectName
                }
              >
                {filteredArray?.map((option) => (
                  <MenuItem key={option.selectName} value={option.selectName}>
                    {option.selectName}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </TextField>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="location"
                name="location"
                size="small"
                {...AssignSearchesForm.getFieldProps("location")}
                error={
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.location &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.location
                }
                helperText={
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.location &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.location
                }
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="Select Age"
                name="selectAge"
                size="small"
                {...AssignSearchesForm.getFieldProps("selectAge")}
                error={
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.selectAge &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.selectAge
                }
                helperText={
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.selectAge &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.selectAge
                }
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="Count Assign"
                name="countAssigned"
                size="small"
                type="number"
                {...AssignSearchesForm.getFieldProps("countAssigned")}
                error={
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.countAssigned &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.countAssigned
                }
                helperText={
                  AssignSearchesForm.touched.countAssigned &&
                  AssignSearchesForm.errors.countAssigned
                }
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  AssignSearchesForm.handleSubmit();
                }}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Add
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Table teamdata={teamdata} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/preset-ranges-antd-4-19-2-forked-mn88h7?file=/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your logic for the way you are calculating the count:

```
const totalRemainingCount =
    totalUsers -
    (parseInt(
      AssignSearchesForm.values.countAssigned
        ? AssignSearchesForm.values.countAssigned
        : 0,
      10
    ) + teamdata?.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a.countAssigned, 0));
```

You were getting `NaN` because the data you were trying to use for subtraction was not the number. Here, I am doing the sum of countAssigned in the table and adding it with the form data that will allow you to get the right value.

Here is an example:https://codesandbox.io/s/preset-ranges-antd-4-19-2-forked-kczd1y?file=/App.js:1838-2095

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood so far is that the `Total count` is not setting properly. If this is the case then you need to set state of count when you click `add` button, so that it stores the `countAssigned` value. Also using the `max` property in `TextField` to limit the count to remaining value.

I have edited your codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/preset-ranges-antd-4-19-2-forked-fm9jpj).

Comment: you understand properly but max property in TextField to limit the count to the remaining value. that I think is not useful because we need to validate count means the user is only able to use that ```Total count``` so  after that count get zero so then in the text field if the user tries or add number and click on ADD button need to throw an error so by using max in text field I am not sure it correct

Comment: you can remove if you want but instead of throwing error after user click add, why not prevent this to happen by using max Or just disable the `add` button?

Comment: but by using max property it will not work for all cases mean only it works if I use less and greater symbol either if I edit on that case max will not work for reference you can check the code sandbox link I added max property